# Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org" Proxy authentication required

Tags: proxy, authentication, gnome-shell-extension

Software updates through Ubuntu Software are failing with the following message:
Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org":[*/*/*/source/shell-extensions/*] failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json:Proxy Authentication Required

I've tried almost all methods listed on the internet.
Added proxy authentication in bashrc using 
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ (for http, https and ftp)
P.S. Since my password contains @, as suggested in other answers I've tried replacing with %40, still no luck.
Added them in /etc/apt/apt.conf in the proper format
Added them in gsettings using shell script

But still the problem is persisting. Installing softwares through terminal is working smoothly as it reads the required proxy authentication details from bashrc or apt.conf. Really don't understand why Ubuntu Software is not able to read the proxy authentication details and connect to the gnome site.